# Keybase API use in PHP application

Tags: php, api, keybase

I am creating a new PHP application in which I want to interact with Keybase.
First option is to use the API, but unfortunately I am running into some issues.

First step is to call the signup call.
I managed to create a curl request, but I am not sure what the pwh should look like. 
I tried:

```
$fp = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
if ($fp !== FALSE) {
    $prBits .= @fread($fp,16);
    @fclose($fp);
}

$salt =  bin2hex($prBits);
$pwh = implode(unpack("H*",password_hash('MyP@ssword'.$prBits, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)));
```

But making the call results in:

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 100,
        "desc": "need a PDPKA5 key",
        "name": "INPUT_ERROR"
    },
    "csrf_token": "lgHZIDA4ZjYyNzgy.....86aMrL09"
}
```

The complete call:

```
$data = [
    "name" => "My Name",
    "email" => "mymail@example.com",
    "username" => "SomeUnusedUsername1234",
    "pwh" => $pwh,
    "pwh_version" => 3,
    "salt" => $salt,
    "invitation_id" => "000000001"
);
$dataString = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://keybase.io/_/api/1.0/signup.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Anyone got a working example or solution?

Comment: Why are you doing a `bin2hex()` on the result of `password_hash()`? That function doesn't return a binary string.

Comment: Hmmm not sure how I overlooked that. But now I changed it, the error still remains.